# Getting available space in dropbox

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox

I have integrated dropbox sdk in IPhone app. I'm uploading files to dropbox. how can I find out how much space is available through code so that I dont upload files when their is no available space

```
    DBQuota *quota=[[DBQuota alloc]init];
    long spaceConsumed=quota.totalConsumedBytes;

    long totalSpace=quota.totalBytes;

    NSLog(@"spaceConsumed %ld",spaceConsumed);
    NSLog(@"total space %ld",totalSpace);
```

here I'm getting output 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `/account/info` method and do some math with the `quota_info` fields.

Documentation here: [/account/info](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#account-info)

**Edit**:
First, you'll need to [set up a session](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/authentication). This will give you a `DBSession` object. Using that `DBSession`, create a `DBRestClient`. Than you can [call methods from the API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/files#ios). For example call `loadAccountInfo`. If all goes well, the delegate method `restClient:loadedAccountInfo:` will be called. That will provide you with a properly assigned object for the quota.

In your example, you just create a new instance of a `DBAccountInfo`, without using the API.

Comment: that's because you're not using the API, but merely creating a new intance.

Comment: -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo *)info
{
    NSLog(@"load account info");
    long spacecConsumed=info.quota.totalBytes;
    
    long totalSpace=info.quota.totalConsumedBytes;
    
    NSLog(@"spaceConsumed %ld",spacecConsumed);
    NSLog(@"total space %ld",totalSpace);

 
}
but delegate method is not being called

Comment: Did you assign a delegate to the `DBRestClient`?

Comment: Have you implemented `restClient:loadAccountInfoFailedWithError:` to see what might be the problem?

Comment: yes i hav implemented but even that method is not getting called. I hav implemented other method those are getting called

Comment: @user2185354, did you ever figure out this issue? I am also not getting the delegate method called